# Apply component to template in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a simple component, using a template like this:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;" #control>Content here</span>
```

Then, in the call site I fiddle with the styling:

```
<my-comp style="width:300px;"></my-comp>
```

...which accomplishes absolutely nothing. At run-time, the above translates to this:

```
<my-comp style="width:300px;" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
  <span style="display:inline-block;" #control>Content here</span>
</my-comp>
```

Fabulous. On `<my-comp>`, the width is being ignored, and on the `<span>` where I want it, it doesn't get applied.

I know I can make the width a property of my component and then apply it in the template, but my question is broader than that: What if I don't want to be prescriptive about the styling being applied? Is there a way to let attributes from the call site automatically be applied to the outer element of the template?

Comment: Could you please explain in simple words what exactly you want?

Comment: Can you please try `<my-comp style="width:300px;display:block;">`. If it doesn't work please provide a Plunker. I don't think this is related to Angular2 but a plain CSS issue.

Comment: @micronyks Those were my simple words :) What did you find unclear?

Comment: Words are not complex to understand. For me I dont understand what exactly you want. That is what i want to know maybe in other words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a custom component is rendered as being `inline` in the browser, which means you can't add a width to it, unless you change its positioning (`absolute` / `fixed`) or change the display (`block` / `inline-block` / `flex` / `inline-flex`).

So either change the style inline (frowned upon), or add a css rule to your component:

```
@Component({
   selector : 'my-comp',
   template : `...`,
   styles : [`:host{display: inline-block}`]
})
export class MyCompComponent {}
```